# Enabling USB debugging from open file system access using custom recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, file-system, usb-debugging

Of course this should be possible, but finding the correct files to modify is the real question.

Assuming we can boot into a custom recovery and have full access to the file system, has anyone investigated the steps for enabling USB debugging?

The motivation for this request is that I have a device that will not fully boot, so a log dump would be very helpful in this case.

Comment: See my answer for [How to enable USB Debugging in Android if forgotten pattern for screen-unlock?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/112111)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct file to modify is the build prop. Which can be risky to modify. This will enable everything needed. Through the file system modify the build.prop or with a computer. If the custom recovery is TWRP or possibly CWM. Then adb comes pre-enabled. Then you also need root and a computer with adb.

1. boot into your custom recovery.
2. Plug your device into your computer and open an elevated command prompt.
3. Throw these commands.

> adb shell
>
> su
>
> mount -o remount,rw /system
>
> cd /
>
> echo "persist.service.adb.enable=1" >> default.prop
>
> echo "persist.service.debuggable=1" >> default.prop
>
> echo "persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb" >> default.prop
>
> echo "persist.service.adb.enable=1" >> /system/build.prop
>
> echo "persist.service.debuggable=1" >> /system/build.prop
>
> echo "persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb" >> /system/build.prop

I have done it this way with a nexus 4 and since this is the build prop. Here are some [others](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2335799) that have too.