# How to enable USB debugging with broken touchscreen?

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen

I have an Infinix Zero phone whose touch screen is broken. The screen calibration got affected, so the touch screen is not responding. I tried pushing a calibration APK to the phone from my system, but the process requires the USB debugging to be turned on. However, I'm unable to turn it on from my phone.

Comment: Related: [How to enable USB Debugging in Android if forgotten pattern for screen-unlock?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/112040)

Comment: Does your phone supports OTG?

Comment: No, it does not support OTG