# Export list of Downloads (no root)

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, download-manager

I was using Firefox and for some reason it deleted all downloads from the SD card.

I found an in-built app "Downloads" which has a list of all files downloaded to date, listing both Chrome and Firefox downloads.

<sub>Click Image to enlarge</sub>

[image: Downloads]

How can I export a list of filenames (and their respective URLs, if possible) shown in this "Downloads" app?

Comment: Did not the answer  work for you? You haven't responded at all.

Comment: Hey @Firelord sorry I couldn't implement your great answer - I m currently in a city with almost no network (no internet), will reply asap. Thanks for the great answer though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Downloads app  has the name DownloadsProviderUI (`com.android.providers.downloads.ui`). The entries shown by it are not handled by or stored inside its data directory. Instead, the app is just a front-end for DownloadsProvider (`com.android.providers.downloads`).

The information you're seeking is stored inside

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/databases/downloads.db
```

Provided that your OEM has not messed up with the [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) of [DownloadProvider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/+refs), you should be able to backup the app using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb).

## Instructions

1. Setup adb in PC and connect the device, with [USB debugging enabled](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112040/how-enable-usb-debugging), into PC.
2. Launch a shell and execute the command

   ```
   adb backup com.android.providers.downloads
   ```

   Agree for the backup on the device. You should now be having a backup file named `backup.ab`.
3. Follow any of the solution [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/96277) to extract the content from the file. (I prefer [Android Backup Extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor).)

   You should now be having a file named `downloads.db`, possibly under `apps/com.android.providers.downloads/db/` (inside the extracted content).
4. You now have many options to open the database file. You can use GUI solutions like [Sqliteman](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqliteman/files/sqliteman/1.2.2/) or [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). The former one can export the data into an HTML file.

   Anyhow, inside the file, the table `downloads` has the relevant columns, namely: `uri`, `title` and `_data`.

   If you've [sqlite3](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) installed, you can do:

   ```
   sqlite3 downloads.db
   .mode line
   .headers on
   .out info.txt
   select uri,title,_data from downloads
   .quit
   ```

   You should now be having a file `info.txt`. Open it and you would see a structure, such as:

   ```
   uri = http://dl-xda.xposed.info/modules/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy_v471_8ba0b6.apk
   title = XPrivacy
   _data = /data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy_v471_8ba0b6.apk

   uri = non-dwnldmngr-download-dont-retry2download
   title = ProcessMonitor.zip
   _data = /storage/sdcard0/Download/ProcessMonitor.zip
   ```

   There exists other modes for formatting. For e.g., change `.mode` to `csv` and `.out` to `file.csv` and then keep the rest of the commands intact. Execute all the commands  serially and you would end up with a CSV file.

   (You can use `PRAGMA table_info('downloads')` or `.schema downloads` to know the name of all the columns inside the table `downloads`.)

   If required, see [this article](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/tool/) on ZetCode to know what the aforesaid SQL commands does.

Comment: Some Android apps [here](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sqlite) may also be able to view and export the data from the database file.