# Random file downloaded but can't locate

Tags: browser, downloading, malware, notification-bar

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini running Android 4.4.2.

I was browsing the internet (yahoo site) using the most recent update of Dolphin browser (which, was not able to load the webpage). During this process I noticed in my push bar something was downloading. I pulled down my notification bar to see that some file that appeared to read "offline english translator." However as soon as I opened then drop-down notification menu, the download finished and removed itself (not the norm) from the notification bar. I have not been able to locate the file using a search in my OI folder manager. (Is there a place to view all phone downloads?)

I uninstalled dolphin in case it was infected with something.
I've downloaded malwarebytes but it hasn't found anything...

Thoughts/suggestions about my situation?

Comment: I'll just add that prior to yesterday, my phone was having issues for 3-4 days in which dozens of apps constantly crashed. The weather app (wunderground) seemed to crash most often, followed by badgeprovider (and also Picase uploader, Google app, Drive, Samsung Push, Google PArtner, Favorite apps, and others). The apps were just crashing in the background apparently, as I was never using any of those apps directly. I cleared cache data from all the apps I listed, installed all of the most recent updates for all of my apps, and the problem has not occurred since. Not sure if this is related.

Comment: Your description very much sounds like you've got some rogue malware app on your device. The download sounds like an app, so check the app drawer for "uninvited news". Also make yourself a note which apps you've recently installed. One of those is the most likely candidate responsible for the download.

Comment: If the download was done through native Download manager, then you may be able to find out where the file was downloaded and what initiated that download. Related: [Export list of Downloads (no root)](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/128844). The next time you happen to be in same situation, install busybox and run a find query, such as `adb shell find /sdcard/ -mmin -X`. It will list all the files modified/created under the last X minutes. You can still try it but the output could be too large for you to handle.