# .com.google.chrome files in my Downloads

Tags: applications

I have a bunch of files in my "Downloads" folder with names that start with ".com.google.chrome".
What are these files?  Is it possible that they are failed downloads?

Comment: If they are  downloads (failed or not), then you can find out what initiated those downloads and from what URL were they supposed to fetch their remaining parts. `/data/data/com.android.providers.downloads/databases/downloads.db` can tell you that. Related: [Export list of Downloads (no root)](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/128844)