# How can i activate, if it's possible, usb debug mode from fastboot in a 3rd gen moto g?

Tags: fastboot, motorola-moto-g, usb-debugging

It is basically dad, it's possible from  fastboot mode to activate de usb debug mode, and if it is, how can i?

Answer (score 1):

I was just commenting on another similar question. Is your phone rooted? You can [try this post's solutions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/112040/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android-if-forgotten-pattern-for-screen-unlock) to see if one of the methods work.

I believe you can flash a custom recovery via fastboot in case it's not present. 
Eg. -

```
fastboot flash recovery <<recovery-name.img>>
fastboot reboot-bootloader
Then use volume keys to select recovery, power button to enter.
```

Comment: Adding to this: at least TWRP on multiple devices supports being "booted" without being "flashed": `fastboot boot <twrp.img>`. So no modifications needed, plus it should even work with the bootloader locked.

Comment: "it should even work with bootloader locked" - Isn't this a huge security flaw? Now anyone can access everything from the recovery without a hassle. Is there a discussion somewhere where I may read up?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really the case (never tried it), so I might be wrong here. But the main advantage I wanted to point out is: no modifications of the installed recovery system are needed that way. And that is true :)