# How to enable debugging in ASUS Zenfone Selfie Pro 4 without seeing the screen (touch works BTW)?

Tags: adb, fastboot, broken-screen, bootloader-lock

[The similar questions are related to other devices and I don't intend to do factory reset.]

I cannot see what is being 'shown' on the screen, only interact through fastboot or randomly touching the screen.
The wifi is also working.

If I could enable debugging, I could use scrcpy to see and interact using mouse on a linux computer.

I suppose I can use fastboot to root/unlock/install apps. But I have no experience doing that. The only command I succeeded was this:

```
fastboot -s H7AZCY5468078HN oem device-info
...
(bootloader)    Device tampered: false
(bootloader)    Device unlocked: false
(bootloader)    Device critical unlocked: false
(bootloader)    Charger screen enabled: false
(bootloader)    Display panel: 
(bootloader)    Sysconf ssn: H7AZCY5468078HN
(bootloader)    Sysconf adb enable: 0
(bootloader)    Sysconf reboot reason: 0
(bootloader)    Sysconf isn: N0CZ1738MB0033372
OKAY [  0.110s]
finished. total time: 0.110s
```

Also, touch-guessing until enabling debug seems impossible in practice.

ps.
My ASUS Zenfone Selfie Pro 4 graphics chip burned and the screen is completely blank after boot.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159551
you can't use fastboot this will factory reset
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/212832

Comment: Duplicate of [Enable ADB and/or change USB connection mode on Galaxy S7 w/ broken screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159551/enable-adb-and-or-change-usb-connection-mode-on-galaxy-s7-w-broken-screen) and [Is there a way to enable USB debugging from fastboot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/212832/218526).

Comment: i am not sure where you have information that graphic chip is burned, but anyway i would try to connect a TV with USB MHL/HDMI adapter

Comment: When the screen is on, it is very hot (untouchable) at the top left corner, and a blue spot appeared there due to heat. It can be something after the graphics chip as well, since this kind of device is usually a SoC.