# How can I unbrick my Sony Xperia M?

Tags: cyanogenmod

So, I was trying to install CyanogenMod using [this guide](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_nicki).

However, as you've probably guessed, this didn't work quite how it should have...

Probably because I forgot to root. I straight out, didn't root my phone. I unlocked the bootloader like it says in the CyanogenMod Wiki, etc etc, and I believe that I did everything correct in terms of Fastboot, etc, but I forgot to root, which means when I try to install the OS from the .zip on the SD Card, it fails. I can't remember the error, but it's something bad, I can remember that.

I wiped it, which worked, but now I can't install anything

Does anyone have any other ideas? I can provide more details if needed.

Oh, and if it helps, when I do sideload and... sideload the package, everything goes fine (I used TWRP this time instead of CyanogenMod Recovery, and went to Advanced > Sideload) until the error appears, right at the end:

> E:Unable to mount '/data'>

The whole phone is full of "unable to mount" stuff. This is why I assume that it was a lack of root. The phone doesn't have permissions to access... itself I guess. TWRP then gives me the "Reboot now" button, I press it, the Sony logo comes and goes a bit, the USB cable still plugged in, then I press the volume buttons a bit, then CyanogenMod Recovery appears again... A picture of an Android with the blue apex type thing spins, then the menu appears with an Android lying on the floor, open, with an exclamation mark in a red triangle...

Comment: It's a long shot but from recovery do you have the option to perform a Factory Reset? /data is where user data is stored in Android. From recovery you could also try wiping /data (you might as well, because you can't really access your /data anyway)

Comment: You could also try to flash stock firmware and start the CM install over again using [this tool by Sony](http://developer.sonymobile.com/services/flash-tool/)

Comment: @Ankush Flashtool isn't supported on the Sony Xperia M...  Only the M2.  I've tried before, it won't work.  I tried doing a factory reset, I can see at the bottom it says "Formatting /data  |  E:  Failed to mount /data (Invalid argument)  |  E:  format_volume failed to mount /data, formatting instead"

Comment: [This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2697277) might be worth a shot

Comment: And just making sure, you didn't encrypt your device before trying to flash CM, right?

Comment: @Ankush No, I didn't encrypt it.  But,  the guide says I need to enable unknown sources and USB Debugging.  Is it possible to do from the CyanogenMod Recovery screen I get when I boot the phone?  Could another img for the recovery do it?

Comment: [This may help](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77280/allow-unknown-sources-from-terminal-without-going-to-settings-app)

Comment: @Ankush Will that work even if there is no OS installed,  just CMRecovery?   And how would I go about enabling USB Debugging,  or is that already enabled by default in the position that I'm in?